# How to map view and viewmodel SPA

Tags: javascript, mvvm, durandal

I am follwing the course about Single page application from pluralsight.
http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/single-page-apps-jumpstart

If you guy saw the example solution in the course you will that there are two views and two viewmodels. 
What i need to do based on this example it's add a treeview control and the top of the page (using kendo ui treeview and dialog jquery ui control). Now the question it's:
How can I add this treeview control as a new view in my Single Page application?

```
function boot() {
        router.mapNav('home');
        router.mapNav('details');
        log('AquaVet Loaded!', null, true);
        return router.activate('home');
    }
```

In the shell class of the application you can see that view/viewmodles are mapped.

and after that in the navigation view these are used:

```
 <div class="btn-group" data-bind="foreach: router.visibleRoutes">
        <a data-bind="css: { active: isActive }, attr: { href: hash }, text: name" 
            class="btn btn-info" href="#"></a>
    </div>
```

What about i want add a new view wich shoul be not in the navigation menu.. how ca i distinct between view in the navigation menu and views places in other places (like a treeview) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the course you will see that there is a nav view that is not in the main menu. The nav view is a pure html view that is composed into the shell view. My point is you can embed views wherever you want, using the compose binding from Durandal.